# what is the proper way to do config lookups in react?

Tags: reactjs

My React app currently uses my local API when making an axios.get() call with the following url:

http://localhost:3000/users

Instead of hard-coding the url, I need my component to do a lookup against the config file that is currently configured for the current environment.  For example, when my API is running on Azure the axios get call should use the following url:

https://my-api.azurewebsites.net/users

What is the proper way to lookup this config value in a React app?  For example, should I create some type of config.js file?  What is the proper import/code for my component to hook into the config file for lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), because this package was designed for server-side app - it injects config variables in the `process.env` dictionary, but the `process` global variable only exists in Node apps and is not available in the browser.

There are many other ways to do what you want, perhaps the simplest I can think of is to have a config file that exports values, and the values it exports depends on the environment the scripts runs in:

```
// config.js
const isProd = location.host === 'my-app.azurewebsites.net'; // or any other check

const devConfig = {
  axiosBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'
}

const prodConfig = {
  axiosBaseUrl = 'https://my-app.azurewebsites.net'
}

export default isProd ? prodConfig : devConfig
```

```
// upon starting your app, before making any axios call
import config from './config';
const http = axios.create({
  baseUrl: config.axiosBaseUrl
});

// use as such
http.get('/hello-world');
// locally: makes a call to http://localhost:3000/hello-world
// in production: makes a call to https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/hello-world
```

<sub>You can also have a config file which contents depends on the build environment, but that would be more complex to setup and is highly dependent on your build pipeline and there's no details about it in your question.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can create a config file or can use `environment variables`.

For environment variables:

1. Create `.env` file in the root directory of your project.
2. Save your URL as `REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/`

Now you can access your base URL when you are making `axios` requests like this:

```
process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL
```

Comment: `dotenv` was designed for Node. `process` is not a global variable that exists in React apps, that are web apps that runs in the browser. This won't work.

Comment: @NinoFiliu My solution does work. Check this out if you want to make sure. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Your solution does not work for apps that are not created by `react-create-app`, or that use a build process that doesn't inject `.env`-defined variables into `process.env`